# javascript - check if string is in a array without case sensitive

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a filter. Where if you input a word that is in the 'blacklist' it will tell something. I've got all the code but have a problem.

**JS:**

```
input = document.getElementById("input").value;
array = ["1","2","3"];
function filter() {
  if (input == array)
  // I will do something.
  } else {
  // Something too
  }
}
```

I want to make it so that if the `input` is a item in the `array`. That the statement is true. But what is the correct way to do this? Because what I'm doing here doesn't work! **Also I want to get rid of the case sensitive!** So that if the array has `hello` in it both `hello` and `Hello` are detected.

Sorry if this question is asked before. I searched for it but didn't know what keywords to use.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I am changing my question a little bit:
I want to check what is in my original question but with some other features.

I also want to check if `input` has a part of an item in `array`. So that if the input is `hello` that `helloworld` is being detected because is has `hello` in it. As well as `hello` or `Hello`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623272/how-to-check-if-a-string-array-contains-one-string-in-javascript

Comment: I think the keyword can be 'javascript array contains some item', 'javascript check item is in array' or 'javascript input is a item in the array(just copy your word)', it should not be hard to think if you know what you want....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `indexOf`:

```
if (array.indexOf(input) > -1)
```

It will be -1 if the element is not contained within the array.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of the case sensitive, so that if I have  `hello`. In the array both `hello` and `Hello` are detected?

Comment: @Finiox No probems, you'd have to use `map` for case insensitivity and map your values into a temporay array containing the uppercase values, then convert your input to uppercase and do the comparison. It's described in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718349/how-do-i-make-array-indexof-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
input = document.getElementById("input").value;
array = ["1","2","3"];
function filter() {
   if (array.indexOf(input) >= 0)
      // I will do something.
    } else {
      // Something too
    }
}
```

The indexOf Method is member of the array type and returns the index (beginning at 0) of the searched element or -1 if the element was not found.

Comment: The more commonly used is `> -1`. I would use this to avoid any further confusion for the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for [is](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

```
input = document.getElementById("input").value;
array = ["1","2","3"];
function filter() {
  if (array.indexOf(input) !== -1 )
  // I will do something.
  } else {
  // Something too
  }
}
```

Comment: If fore some reason `indexOf` returned undefined, or null, this will return a false positive

Comment: from the doc "This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs"