# Javascript - Case insensitive Array Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

This code gets rid of all the duplicate variables. Is there a way to make the array search in this function case insensitive?

```js
var x = ["AAA", "aaa", "bbb", "BBB"];

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}

// Output should be AAA, bbb
console.log(unique(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Associated [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/anbrtogo/4/)

Comment: do `x = x.map(el => el.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Honestly, the easiest way is to just `.toLowerCase()` on everything, so that there is a always the same case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Array.indexOf() case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718349/how-do-i-make-array-indexof-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't need jQuery.
- Use the function `findIndex` and convert to lowerCase every element for each comparison.

```js
var x = ["AAA", "aaa", "bbb", "BBB"];

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  list.forEach(function(e) {
    if (result.findIndex(function(r) {
      return r.toLowerCase() === e.toLowerCase();
    }) === -1)
    
    result.push(e);
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(unique(x))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using arrow functions:

```js
var x = ["AAA", "aaa", "bbb", "BBB"];

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  list.forEach((e) => {
    if (result.findIndex((r) => r.toLowerCase() === e.toLowerCase()) === -1)   
    result.push(e);
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(unique(x))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: "A small group of characters, when they are converted to lowercase, cannot make a round trip. To make a round trip means to convert the characters from one locale to another locale that represents character data differently, and then to accurately retrieve the original characters from the converted characters."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookuptable with only lowercase entries:

```
function unique(arr){
  const before = new Set, result = [];

  for(const str of arr){
   const lower = str.toLowerCase();
   if(!before.has(lower)){
    before.add(lower);
    result.push(str);
   }
  }
  return result;
}
```

That in a oneliner:

```
const unique = arr => (set => arr.filter(el => (lower => !set.has(lower) && set.add(lower))(el.toLowerCase()))(new Set);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add .toLowerCase to everything

```
var x = ["AAA", "aaa", "bbb", "BBB"];

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.toLowerCase(), result) == -1) result.push(e.toLowerCase());
  });
  return result;
}

alert(unique(x));
```

Answer (score -1):

just a little tweaking and you will be there

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if($.inArray(e, list)){ result.push(e)};
    });
    return result;
}
```

that works fine

no need to case change
[image: testing the code]